# C++ Issue with cin and CTRL + Z

Tags: c++, windows, eof, cin

I'm reading c++ primer 5th and I have a little problem with an exercise:

> Read a sequence of words from cin and store the values a vector. After
>   you’ve read all the words, process the vector and change each word to
>   uppercase. Print the transformed elements, eight words to a line.

My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(){

    vector<string> words;
    string wordBuffer;
    vector<string> output(1);

    while (cin >> wordBuffer){
        words.push_back(wordBuffer);
    }

    for (string &word : words){
        for (char &letter : word){
            letter = toupper(letter);
        }
    }

    unsigned currentLine = 0;
    for (decltype(words.size())index = 0; index < words.size(); ++index){

        output[currentLine] += words[index] + " ";

        if ((index+1) % 8 == 0){
            ++currentLine;
            output.push_back("");
        }

    }

    for (string s : output){
        s[s.size() - 1] = 0; //removing the whitespace
        cout << s << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, everything works well, but i have an issue with the input of the words by console. 
If I write

> I am writing a random words ^Z

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> nothing happens. I have to rewrite the ^Z after I have pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, like here:

> I am writing a random words
>   ^Z

Can you expain me why? Thanks!

PS: I'm saying that because in my previous programs writing ^Z in the same line worked fine. Like in this code:

```
#include <iostream>;


int main(){
    int currval = 0,val = 0;

        int count = 1;
        while (std::cin >> val){
            if (currval == val){
                ++count;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "The number " << currval << " appears " << count << " times" << std::endl;
                currval = val;
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "The number " << currval << " appears " << count << " times" << std::endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why :(

Comment: Did you write ^Z or press Ctrl+Z? (in the other program)

Comment: This is not a C++ issue but is standard behaviour in Windows. To confirm you can run this simple program and get the same behaviour (CTRL+Z must be pressed on its own line in order to terminate): `char c; while((c = getchar()) != EOF) putchar(c);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ^Z has to be first in order for Windows to treat it as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, otherwise it is just treated as meaningless characters.

If you would like it to work like you wrote i'd suggest:

```
String wordBuffer("")
while (strcmp(wordBuffer[strlen(wordBuffer)-3], "^Z") != 0){
    words.push_back(wordBuffer);
    cin >> wordBuffer
}
```

**EDIT:** in your second example it works because when you read integers c++ knows to divide the given string of numbers in the space (or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> if the numbers are entered separately in every line) to read every number separately so if you'll enter:

```
123 2323 4545 43 ^Z
```

It will read 123, then 2323, ... and then ^Z and so it will be as though it got it in a separate line but when you read string, it cant do that because a string contain every symbol and so it separate the input in the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> pressed and that why the second one works

Comment: so why in my second example it works? This is the thing I can't understand

Comment: For a disk file in text mode, the CRT's [`_read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyssk1bs.aspx) treats CTRL+Z (0x1A) as `EOF` -- regardless of position. That's the case if standard input or `cin` is a file. For a console, as noted, it's actually Windows `ReadFile` that reports 0 read characters if the first byte is CTRL+Z.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is placed in the keyboard buffer before any other entered symbols. Thus any entered characters before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will be discarded. You need to do the following

```
I am writing a random words  ENTER
^Z ENTER
```