# C++ getline(cin, buffer) doesn't stop when I press CTRL+Z

Tags: c++, windows, input, getline, eof

I'm writing a `CLI` application in `Windows` that accepts a `string` as an input. I assume the end of the input is when user presses <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> (that imitates `EOF`).

When I enter "*qwe*" and press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> the `getline` instead of just assigning the "*qwe*" to `tmp` asks me to input one more line for some reason. However, the resulting value in `tmp` is still "*qwe*" ignoring the extra line. The code I use is the following:

```
    string tmp;
    getline(cin, tmp);
```

**UPD:**

As it was said in [C++ Issue with cin and CTRL + Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766486/c-issue-with-cin-and-ctrl-z), it's just the usual Windows behavior, where the <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> symbol `must` be at the beginning of the line.

To get the multiline input you should use read by characters until you meet `'\n' || EOF`.

Comment: hmm, looking in the duplicate theme, when I press CTRL+Z in the beginning of my input then it perfectly works. But if it's in the end or in the middle then it asks for an extra line and assigns everything before '^Z' to tmp and only then moves to the following code line. that's if getline is inside of while

Comment: So is it a question about the behavior of ctrl+z in std::cin or do you simply want to read a file in a string array? Or maybe i understood it wrong?

Comment: I need to read stdin into a string array. that's the task. but i assume they are gonna end input with ctrl+z so I want to make sure getline doesn't ask for input after that. or the user just needs to know how to use ctrl+z to? that seems strange. however the task is gonna be checked by codeforces.com i mean by the server, so maybe i just need to leave it as it is

Comment: Why do you need an array? You need to split the input string? How is the data inputted(if thats a word)?

Comment: well, it's just stdin so it should imitate keyboard (maybe just past data, like i do with ctrl+v). I need an array because I need to process every string and then output. The purpose of the program is to format indentations of the text

Comment: Updated. p.s. Don't look at those comments.

Comment: 6 months.... Not bad

Comment: @Treycos yeah corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by OP: This is typical Windows behavior, where the <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> symbol must be at the beginning of the line or it will not work as expected.

So if you input "foo", then send the `EOF` signal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> and then input "bar", "foo" will be read as expected and then `EOF` will wait in the input buffer until "bar" is typed too. The program, as is, will stop at `EOF` and "bar" will be ignored, even though the user typed it.

Read more in [C++ Issue with cin and CTRL + Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766486/c-issue-with-cin-and-ctrl-z).

Comment: Well, yeah, that is exactly the same what I wrote above.

Comment: @Sam pretty much yes, but answers should be placed in the answer section, that's why I thought it was a good idea to post an answer. =)

Comment: The idea is indeed good :)